# Is there a solution for accepting payments with Paypal with or without UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, paypal, uiwebview

I have final data such as clothing item, colour, size and total price ready to check out. All I need now is a way to allow the user to pay for their items.

I've downloaded the PayPal iOS SDK and looked at the demo app but still not sure where to start because of code all over the place. All I need is a simple check out. My app already works out the total price of items. So I just need PayPal to allow the customer to pay for the goods.

I understand I need a Paypal sandbox account and an AppID. But interested in finding a clear step by step tutorial on how to do this in an iOS 7 app.

Been hunting for half the day but there doesn't seem to be many tutorials on how to do this.

Would appreciate some guidance or a kick in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you taken a look at: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guide explains very well: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md